# Bind VIewModels to ajax loaded TabStrip tabs

Tags: tabs, kendo-ui, viewmodel, partial

I have a tab strip on my Razor View that looks like this:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
          .Name("tabstrip")
          .Items(tabstrip =>
          {
              foreach (var tab in @Model.Tabs.Values)
              {
                  tabstrip.Add().Text(tab.Title)
                  .LoadContentFrom(tab.Title.Replace(" ", string.Empty), "Account"); //remove spaces for action methods
              }
          })
    )
```

The controller returns a partial view for each tab. The main View is bound to a view model called AccountViewModel, which has a Dictionary called Tabs. Tabs maps strings to ViewModels for each individual tab.

On each iteration of the foreach loop, *tab* is actually the ViewModel I would like to bind to the lab being loaded.

Is there a way to bind the ViewModel, let's say, Tabs["tabA"] to the partial view returned by LoadContentFrom("tabA", "Account");?

Comment: What do you mean by to bind the ViewModel to the Partial View? You want the `LoadContentFrom("tabA", "Account")` to return a strongly-typed Partial View with Tabs["tabA"] as Model, is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Tabs["tabA"] would be the *tab* iterator.

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done because the tabs will be loaded by an ajax request. Your action methods that return the partial result need to properly set the model of that partial view.

The other option is to avoid using LoadContentFrom:

```
foreach (var tab in @Model.Tabs.Values)
{
   tabstrip.Add().Text(tab.Title)
           .Content(@Html.Partial(/* partial view name */ tab.Title, /* view model */ tab));        
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I need LoadContentFrom, because I need to use ajax.